# After 1.0.1 update Meteor is filling up tmp folder

Tags: linux, meteor

I just ran the Meteor 1.0.1 patch and now my app is no longer useable. It fills up the /tmp folder within 1 minute of running Meteor.

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/hdv1             3.6T  709G  2.9T  20% /
none                  128M  128M     0 100% /tmp
```

I have no idea of even how to start to try and fix this. Server is Debian Linux. Any ideas?

Comment: Help people to help you by posting code that will reproduce the problem. This need not be all your code.  Less code is always preferred, so long as it reproduces the problem....

Comment: There really is no specific code. I just do meteor run and then watch tmp fill up. With over 10,000 lines of code I wouldn't know where to start. I can do a deployment to my Modulus server and everything seems to be running fine over there for the last two hours. I know that modulus "demeteorizes" the code so if it is my code causing this it's getting removed or fixed in that process.

Comment: This is what the server says before crashing;  events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event. Error: ENOSPC, write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that Meteor is trying to download the new release in the background and your `/tmp` partition is too small. It looks like Meteor needs about 250MB to complete the update.

You can work around this in a couple ways. First, you could increase the size of your tmp partition.  Or, you could specify the `TMPDIR` environment variable to make Meteor use a different directory for the installation. Eg:

```
mkdir ~/temp
env TMPDIR=~/temp meteor update
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Apparently the update never completed. root@ps376193:~/onepage# env TMPDIR=~/temp meteor update
Sorry, Meteor 1.0.1 is not installed and could not be
downloaded. Please check to make sure that you are online.
root@ps376193:~/onepage# meteor --version
Meteor 1.0

Comment: Did you make sure ~/temp exists (the mkdir command above)? This is the same error you get if the TMPDIR does not exist yet.

Comment: I had my VPS Host move /tmp to the disk. Meteor launched and stayed up. Then I did meteor --version and after about 7 minutes it showed Meteor 1.0.1 and all was well in the World. Thanks for the help!